# Make a square contour plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't get matplotlib to make a contour plot with equal x and y axes. Note that I try defining the figure with equal figsize (10,10) and also try 'equal' in the axis function. Neither work, as is show by the "circle" that is a oval:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

# generate 2 2d grids for the x & y bounds
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(0, 1 + 0.1, 0.1),
                slice(0, 1 + 0.1, 0.1)]

z = y + x
z = z[:-1, :-1]
levels = MaxNLocator(nbins=15).tick_values(z.min(), z.max())

# pick the desired colormap, sensible levels, and define a normalization
# instance which takes data values and translates those into levels.
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(10,10))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('nipy_spectral')
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

# contours are *point* based plots, so convert our bound into point centers
plt.contour(x[:-1, :-1] + 0.1 / 2.,
            y[:-1, :-1] + 0.1 / 2., z, levels=levels,
            cmap=cmap, zorder=1)

plt.colorbar()
plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1],'equal')
plt.tight_layout()

circle=plt.Circle((0.4,0.5),.1,color='k',fill=False)
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

plt.savefig('not_square')
```

Comment: Try `ax = plt.gca()` and then `ax.set_aspect('equal')`.

Comment: That does it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a square plot try `plt.axis('square');`

```
def f(x, y):
    return x ** 2 + y ** 2

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 50)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 50)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='black');
plt.axis('square');
```

[image]